# Read capacity units consumption in DynamoDB for Scan operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table with 20 items. Each item consists of "id" (number) and "state" (string). "id" in in range from "1" to "20". "state" can be any of strings "ACTIVE", "INACTIVE", "FREEZE". I'm calling Scan to get all the items

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name test-table --return-consumed-capacity TOTAL
```

In the response I see

```
ConsumedCapacity":{"CapacityUnits":2.0,"TableName":"test-table"}
```

I don't get it. With debug flag I see that the whole response body is 929 bytes

```
...
'Content-Length': '929'
...
```

My understanding is that DynamoDB should round it up to 1 KB which means 0.5 read unit, not 2. According to the documentation

> One read capacity unit represents one strongly consistent read per
> second, or two eventually consistent reads per second, for an item up
> to 4 KB in size

I perform eventually consistent read all my table is under 4 KB, so I don't understand where this 2 capacity unites come from.

Can anybody help me understand this?

Comment: I guess that `Content-Length` is the amount of data transferred to you over the internet using HTTP AND _compression_ (like gzip). Read capacity units are calculated before the content is compressed and send over the wire and depend on the actual size of the table. You can check the size of the table using AWS CLI or console. `aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name <table-name> --query 'Table.TableSizeBytes'`

Comment: @Jens A little comment to this. `TableSizeBytes` is often 0 for new tables, as this data is not calculated in real time by aws.

Comment: @Marcin Thank you for the hint. At least in the Console you can force re-calculation (by using the "Get live item count" button). As far as I know it should only show 0 for new tables for which the size has not yet been calculated, which as you stated is not real time but happens from time to time.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I've tried to run `aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name test-table`. And got `TableSizeBytes: 310`. It sounds right. As every item is sum of column names and values (size("id") + size("state") + size("20") + size("INACTIVE")). According to my calculation the table should not be larger than 380 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ProvisionedThroughput.html#ProvisionedThroughput.CapacityUnits.Read):

> Scan reads all items in a table. DynamoDB considers **the size of the items that are evaluated**, not the size of the items returned by the scan.

So it is about the actual total size of your items in the table, not the size of what is returned to you.

Comment: Right. I'm aware of this. As you can see I run `scan` without any filters, so dynamodb should evaluate and return all the itmes.